# How to solve oversegmented whole white blood cell by watershed in MATLAB or others

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

As the picture, I would like to separate adjacent cells by watershed algorithm, but the result shows oversegmented. How could I use imimposemin() to solve this problem. Thank you!

```
WATESHED CODE in MATLAB:
D = -bwdist(~BW);
D(~BW)  =-Inf;
L = watershed(D,8);
BW(L==0)=0;
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd4zh.png)

[Input BW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R66MU.png)

Comment: RGB of input BW   http://i.stack.imgur.com/nex5R.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. compute the distance map or the ultimate eroded (more stable)
2. Dilate the result in order to merge the close patterns
3. use the result as inner seeds.

You get [this result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/ResWat_R66MU.png).

[EDIT] Here is [the result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/ResWat_R66MUbis.png) when I use the gradient computed on the original image. But be careful, in order to preserve the global shape, I had to merge the gradient and the contour of the binary mask, [see here](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/ResWat_R66MUgrad.png).

Comment: Thank for your reply!